# JQuery Tooltipster Delay On Click

Tags: jquery, click, settimeout, tooltipster

I have a JQuery slideshow on my home page that displays a tooltip (using the plugin Tooltipster http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/), each time you hover over one of the slideshow images. What I want to do is delay the loading of Tooltipster every time the next button on the slideshow is clicked using JQuery. This is my syntax so far:

```
<!--- Load Tooltipster plugin -->

<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
});
    </script>

<!--- Delay the plugin load every time next_button is clicked -->    

<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".next_button").bind("click",function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster();}, 200);
  });
});
 </script>
```

However this is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `$` before `document` as well as `$` to select your `.next_button`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".next_button").bind("click",function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster();}, 200);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah yes sorry, my mistake. This doesn't fix the problem however.

Comment: @MatthewCooper try to use `on()` instead of `bind()`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Do I have to stop "$('.tooltip').tooltipster();" before I can set it to timeout?

Comment: @MatthewCooper I'd suggest you always try everything in programming since it's actually one of the best way to help you improving your skill :)

Comment: I don't know how to stop it though.

Comment: @MatthewCooper try using `stop()`: `$('.tooltip').stop(true).tooltipster()`. But actually, it's quite difficult since you didn't post any demo to explain your situation.